# What is the difference between position_min and position_endstop parameters in Klipper config file?

Tags: klipper

I have a Tronxy VEHO-600 and I have a config file, which I got from a friend. My question is regarding the following code block:

```
[stepper_x]
step_pin: PE5
dir_pin: !PF1
enable_pin: !PF0
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 60
endstop_pin: !PC15
position_endstop: -5
position_min: -5
position_max: 600 # for bed mesh
homing_speed: 200
homing_retract_dist: 10
second_homing_speed: 10.0

[stepper_y]
step_pin: PF9
dir_pin:  PF3
enable_pin: !PF5
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 60
endstop_pin: !PC14
position_endstop: -10
position_min: -10
position_max: 600
homing_retract_dist: 10
homing_speed: 100.0
second_homing_speed: 10.0
```

Is `position_min` how far off the bed the axis needs to go to hit the end stop? I think it is not, as there is a `position_endstop` declaration just above it, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

These parameters are related to the minimum position of the axis, but they have slightly different usages.

The **`position_min`** parameter refers to the lowest possible position of the axis, regardless of the endstop position. It is used to prevent the axis from going too far in one direction, which could cause damage to the printer. It specifies the minimum physical position that the motor can be set to, regardless of the endstop position.

The **`position_endstop`** parameter specifies the physical position of the endstop switch relative to the axis, which is used during homing operations to determine the actual position of the axis. When the motor reaches this position, it will trigger the endstop switch and stop the motor from moving any further in that direction.

Comment: Nice to see some Klipper questions being answered! I hope that you can create some questions and answers on Klipper for others to learn from your experience!